# Adding a 3rd Party JAR to Maven Repo

Tags: java, maven

I just needed to use a 3rd party JAR in my project and deployed the JAR in my local maven repo. I followed these steps while doing this:

->Runned the belowed statement:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\DEVEL\gsa-japi-src-1.3.jar -DgroupId=net.sf.gsaapi 
-DartifactId=gsaapi -Dversion=1.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```

->I saw "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" message, checked local repo files and it seemed the deployment was succesfull.

->After installed and deployed, i just added following statements in pom.xml file.

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.gsaapi</groupId>
      <artifactId>gsaapi</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

But I still can not reach the library's methods. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gsa-japi-src-1.3.jar contains only source files (.java) and apidocs. You need a jar with .class files

Comment: How can i obtain .class files? The library's official download site doesnt have any option like that.

Comment: @metzelder http://sourceforge.net/projects/gsa-japi/files/gsa-japi/1.10/ which I found by looking at the project's files.

Comment: Oh sorry, i missed that one! So now, i need to maven install again with the file directory  that contains .class and other files, dont i?

Answer (score 1):

Correct dependency is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.gsaapi</groupId>
  <artifactId>gsa-japi-src</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have editted the statement. It was added by fault to the question.

Comment: i edited my answer too. check that gsa-japi-src jar contains classes as requested by @Evgeniy Dorofeev

Answer (score 0):

You have installed JAR use `net.sf.gsaapi:gsaapi` artifact identifier but in dependency you are using `com.google.code:kaptcha`. So, you should use the same artifact identifier in dependencies.

Comment: I have edited the dependency statement. The last one was added by fault.